# Zebra Enterprise Browser Launch issue on Emulator

Tags: browser, android-emulator, enterprise, zebra-printers

[image]

Hi,

I am new to android & currently trying to simulate Zebra Enterprise browser on Android Emulator. Below Configuration I have used -

### AVD :

Name: HDT_zebra_API_23

CPU/ABI: Google APIs ARM (armeabi-v7a)

Path: C:\Users****.android\avd\HDT_zebra_API_23.avd

Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 23)

Skin: 1080x1920

SD Card: 100 MiB

hw.dPad: no

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: HDT_zebra

vm.heapSize: 2048

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: User

hw.gps: yes

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

skin.path.backup: _no_skin

image.androidVersion.api: 23

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-23\google_apis\armeabi-v7a\

hw.cpu.model: cortex-a8

tag.id: google_apis

showDeviceFrame: no

hw.camera.back: emulated

hw.mainKeys: no

AvdId: HDT_zebra_API_23

hw.camera.front: emulated

hw.lcd.density: 480

avd.ini.displayname: HDT_zebra API 23

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.device.hash2: MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88

hw.ramSize: 2048

hw.trackBall: no

PlayStore.enabled: false

hw.battery: yes

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google APIs

runtime.network.latency: none

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

disk.dataPartition.size: 1G

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes

---

I have successfully installed Zebra Enterprise browser APK to AVD by referring link -https://techdocs.zebra.com/enterprise-browser/2-0/guide/setup/#connections

Now main issue i am facing is to launch browser. Getting message as shown in picture.

I have tried many options like clearing cache, giving storage permission via settings.

Please let me know if you have any other suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Zebra's Enterprise Browser is only validated to work on physical hardware and emulators are not supported.  There will be some hardware dependency causing the launch to fail, most likely the scanner (but that is a guess).  No emulators are available for Zebra devices and you will need to obtain physical hardware... there are ways of getting demo kit if you are in their partner program but that is off-topic.

Comment: Hi, Enterprise Browser is definitely only validated to work on Zebra hardware and there is no claim for support on either personal devices or emulators.  What you are trying to do is not supported

Comment: Hi Samuel - I don't think its fair to downvote Darryn for being the bearer of bad news, however, I appreciate your position and in an ideal world Zebra would indeed offer emulators. We do appreciate your feedback & this is something we're aware of.